# How to rename the result of a query with some conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

As a result of my query I have 3 values in a column. I would need to abbreviate and return the column values. For eg. Say my result is 
World Trade Centre 
I would need it to be printed as WTC

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Look at the CASE keyword

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hi, I am afraid if I am allowed to put the entire query that I have tried. Not sure if this would help. I have used nested queries and able to get the result of the query. But I would want the values to be renamed. For eg. My values (as a result of the query) is Additional Voluntary Contribution but I wanted it to be printed as AVC. I am using the Case statement but in vain

Comment: I m using Oracle database

Comment: Please add a few examples of the values you want to change. A simple example should do. You can use the `CASE` clause as @UnhandledExcepSean said.

Comment: Additional Voluntary Contribution (AVC)
Executive Pension Plan (EPP)
Money Purchase Plan (MPP) --> These are my values. I just wanted it to be returned as just AVC, EPP and MPP in a column. I have already tried using the Case statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expressions for this:

```
select (case when col = 'World Trade Center' then 'WTC'
             . . .
         end) as abbrev
```

The need for something like this actually suggests that you want a reference table for whatever entity this is.  You may find that multiple queries end up doing the same thing -- and then if a fourth value is added, lots of code needs to change.

Comment: I am trying with the Case statement, Im missing something with the syntax. I use something like 'select case when .. then .. end as col_name from table_name'

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I just made for you, it works fine on SQL Server, if you use anything else maybe you'll have to change minor things but it shouldn't be that difficult.
Remember to change VARCHAR size to fit to your database's column.

```
DECLARE @return VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @loop INT
DECLARE @myString VARCHAR(30)

SET @return = '' -- The variable that will be returned
SET @myString = 'World Trade Center' -- Your original value
SET @loop = LEN(@myString) - LEN(REPLACE(@myString,' ','')) + 1 -- Calculate the    nombre of spaces to know how many times to loop

DECLARE @count INT = 1;

WHILE @count <= @loop -- While u haven't parsed all words of the original string
BEGIN
   SET @return = SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@myString, ' ', '.'), @count), 1, 1) + @return -- Add the first letter of each word to the return variable
   SET @count = @count + 1;
END;

SELECT @return -- And there you got 'WTC', you can use it as you want
```

> The adding of the first letter of each word to @return may look strange as it looks like it would add letters in reverse order, but it actually works fine like that, at least on SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

How about a little bit of regular expression?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'World Trade Centre ' from dual union all
  3     select 'Additional Voluntary Contribution' from dual union all
  4     select 'Executive Pension Plan' from dual union all
  5     select 'Money Purchase Plan' from dual
  6    )
  7  select
  8    col,
  9    listagg(substr(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, column_value), 1, 1), '')
 10      within group (order by column_value) result
 11  from test,
 12       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
 14                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15  group by col;

COL                               RESULT
--------------------------------- ----------
Additional Voluntary Contribution AVC
Executive Pension Plan            EPP
Money Purchase Plan               MPP
World Trade Centre                WTC

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- split every string into rows (that's what `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in line 9 does)
- select the first letter of every substring (that's what `SUBSTR` in line 9 does)
- aggregate those first letters into the result (that's what `LISTAGG` does)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what went wrong earlier and what did I do now. But I have tried using the Case Expression and now it worked. 
Thanks All for your inputs.